# Last update query count in amazon redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Is there any way to count last number of rows affected through SQL update query in amazon redshift ?

Similar to function like PG_LAST_COPY_COUNT() to count last copy-count in amazon redshift.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This should give the information

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN d.relname IS NOT NULL THEN d.relname
         ELSE i.relname
       END TableName,
       CASE
         WHEN nvl (Deleted_Rows,0) = 0 THEN nvl (Inserted_Rows,0)
         ELSE 0
       END Inserted_Rows,
       CASE
         WHEN nvl (Deleted_Rows,0) = nvl (Inserted_Rows,0) THEN nvl (Inserted_Rows,0)
         ELSE 0
       END Updated_Rows,
       CASE
         WHEN nvl (Inserted_Rows,0) = 0 THEN nvl (Deleted_Rows,0)
         ELSE 0
       END Deleted_Rows
FROM (SELECT query,
             relname,
             SUM(ROWS) Deleted_Rows
      FROM stl_delete sd
        JOIN pg_class t ON t.oid = sd.tbl
      GROUP BY query,
               relname) d
  FULL JOIN (SELECT query,
                    relname,
                    SUM(ROWS) Inserted_Rows
             FROM stl_insert si
               JOIN pg_class t ON t.oid = si.tbl
             GROUP BY query,
                      relname) i ON i.query = d.query
WHERE CASE WHEN d.query IS NOT NULL THEN d.query ELSE i.query END = pg_last_query_id();
```

Comment: Why and how Updated_Rows ends up coming from stl_delete and stl_insert?

Comment: In redshift, there is no update operation behind the scene. All update goes as delete the record to be updated and insert the updated record as new record

Comment: I'll take your word but is there any official documentation referring this subject? I can't find any evidence of what you are saying is true. I'm insisting with this because I need to have my processes backed with evidence.

Comment: I've verified empirically that what you are saying is true but still it would be nice some backup documentation!

Comment: There is an error on the query, you don't have to get the SUM(ROWS)! redshift logs several records for every slice that the query is distributed but the rows column get the total rows processed, so you should only take one of this values not the sum.

Comment: If distribution style for table is set to ALL, then row count is multiplied by your instance node count.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, there is no equivalent of `PG_LAST_COPY_COUNT()` for capturing the last number of affected rows from a insert/update/delete however you can achieve this by using the system tables `STV_SESSIONS`, `STL_QUERY`,  and `STL_INSERT`. There's a great blog post [here](http://www.sqlhaven.com/amazon-redshift-getting-number-of-records-affected-in-last-query-executed-in-current-session/) about how to build the query.

Hope this helps!